# Does Galaxy Xcover 3 Value Edition support Mifare Classic NFC tags?

Tags: nfc

The Samsung Galaxy Xcover 3 is one of the few devices that still support Mifare Classic NFC tags. It was released in 2015. Now Samsung have released an updated version, the "Value Edition" in 2016.

Does anyone know whether this new version still supports Mifare Classic NFC tags?